How to correctly handle dynamic content height with SliverOverlapAbsorber in NestedScrollView?
I’m working on a Flutter application where I’m using a NestedScrollView with a SliverAppBar, SliverList, and a SliverPersistentHeader that contains a TabBar. My goal is to manage overlapping content correctly, but I’m facing issues due to dynamic content heights between the SliverAppBar and the TabBar. The default usage of SliverOverlapAbsorber isn’t working as expected because of these dynamic heights. Below is the relevant part of my code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyCustomScrollView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyCustomScrollViewState createState() => _MyCustomScrollViewState();
}

class _MyCustomScrollViewState extends State<MyCustomScrollView> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return [
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 200.0,
              floating: false,
              stretch: true,
              pinned: true,
              backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(.1),
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                title: Text("SliverAppBar"),
                background: Image.network(
                  "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  Container(
                    height: 300.0,
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    child: const Center(
                      child: Text("Scrollable Content"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
                TabBar(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  tabs: const [
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                    Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              pinned: true,
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: _tabBarView(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _tabBarView() {
    return TabBarView(
      controller: _tabController,
      children: [
        _someWidgetOne(),
        _someWidgetNestedOne(),
        _someWidgetOne(),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _someWidgetOne() {
    return Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        return Container(
          height: 400.0,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text('Some text'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _someWidgetNestedOne() {
    return Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        return CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text('Item $index'),
                    leading: const Icon(Icons.star),
                    trailing: Text('Detail $index'),
                  );
                },
                childCount: 40,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverAppBarDelegate(this._tabBar);

  final TabBar _tabBar;

  @override
  double get minExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;
  @override
  double get maxExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: _tabBar,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

The layout has dynamic heights which make the standard SliverOverlapAbsorber setup inadequate. I would appreciate if someone could run this code to better understand the behavior and suggest how to manage the overlap properly while keeping the current layout and behavior. If necessary, I am open to using other widgets or approaches as long as they fit within the existing structure.
